# How to import relational database to mongo

Tags: sql, mongodb

what is the best way to import and link a relational database into mongo? 
i have an access database with the following:

```
CustomerTable
  idCustomer --will become idImport in mongo
  name, etc

VehicleTable
  idVehicle   --will become idImport in mongo
  idCustomer  --upon import, need to find and add mongo's customer _id
  idCustomer2 //co owner
  Make, model, etc.
```

the field names will be changed , for Example FirstName becoming nameFirst,  etc.

my first attempt has been using express and exported tables converted to json, but figuring out how to replace/convert the imported ids to the new mongo _id is giving me an issue.

does anyone have a sample of converting a relational database's idImported to it's _id equivilant?

Comment: why can't you just let mongo create its own `_id`s and store the original `id` as a separate property- unless your primary keys happen to already be mongo ObjectIds that is probably what you need to do. If you really want to specify your own _ids look at [the ObjectId documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)

Comment: that's what i've done.  however, after importing customers, i now need to import vehicles and get the mongo customer _id into the vehicle table.updated the question to better reflect this